# Is it possible to reference constants in struct field tag definitions?

Tags: go

I have database and JSON models which use struct field annotation for various purposes, namely specifying enumerations, which values are acceptable for validations, etc.

A database model example:

```golang
type QRCode struct {
    Algorithm  string  `json:"algorithm" gorm:"type:enum('hmac-sha3-256-v1')" validate:"oneof=hmac-sha3-256-v1"`
    PublicCode []byte  `json:"token" gorm:"size:32" validate:"len=32"`
    UserType   string  `json:"user_type" gorm:"type:enum('admin','member')" validate:"one_of=admin member"`

    gorm.Model
}
```

So in this case, there are a few different constants:

- public key size, which I have in `constants.QRCodePublicCodeLength`
- algorithm, which I have in `constants.QRCodeAlgorithmV1`
- user type, which I have in `constants.UserTypeAdmin` and `constants.UserTypeMember`

It would be very nice to be able to embed these constants in the field tags so that there is truly one source of truth for everything, but I don't know if this is possible in Go.

Can I use constants in struct field tag definitions?

Answer (score 4):

> Can I use constants in struct field tag definitions?

No, this is not possible.